# Angular 10 - Dispatch NGXS Action within a Subscribtion causes infinite Loop

Tags: angular, observable, infinite-loop, ngxs

I am calling a NGXS Action with the store.dispatch() function within a subscribtion. I need the data from the subscribed observable before i call the store.dispatch() function and therefore i somehow have to wait for the observable to deliver the data. I dont know how i can fix this code so the loop will be prevented. Does someone of you know how to handle this correctly?

```
@Select(NepoState.anlagen) myObserveable$: Observable<Anlage[]>;
ngOnInit(): void {
      this.myObserveable$.subscribe((data) => {
        this.store.dispatch(new ChangeAvalableFilterAction(data); // <-- this causes the loop 
      })
}
```

Comment: Where do you get your `myObserveable` from?

Comment: From the following line: @Select(NepoState.anlagen) myObserveable$: Observable<Anlage[]>;

Comment: Think of Observables as if you subscribed for a newspaper: You'll receive the latest edition whenever the publisher releases one for as long as you don't unsubscribe. So if your action modifies the state in a way that your anlagen-selector emits a new value: loop! take(1), etc. could be a workaround here, but you need to be okay with receiving just the first value emitted from the Observable. These rxjs-filters will also implicitly unsubscribe (which you should keep an eye on in general). Alternatively, you could also skip these filters and go toPromise(). Hope your project is going well ;-)

Comment: @max thank you for your answer! Yes in the project is everything fine, thanks :) Hope you are doing good at apa. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dispatch from within the `subscribe` is changing the state and firing the selector again. This will dispatch another action and there you have a loop.

You can do following:

```typescript
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.myObserveable$
    .pipe(
      take(1) // either take just one emission, or using first()
      //filter(data => /* or filter according to some condition */)
    )
    .subscribe((data) => {
      this.store.dispatch(new ChangeAvalableFilterAction(data);
    })
}
```